# SocketIO throws "Can't find variable: Reflect" on bad requests if chrome debugger is not connected

Tags: react-native

This is for both Android and IOS. I am using [feathersjs](http://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/socket-io.html) by the way.

Answer (score 2):

It seems one of the causes for this error is not importing `babel-polyfill` as suggested on the docs (for react-native).

Check this issue https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/395

And here the feather's react-native section on the docs
https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/feathers.html#usage-with-react-native